# i.maxlik cannot read i.class output signature file

Tags: grass-gis

I'm trying to perform a supervised classification using i.class. I'm then using i.maxlik, but this is returning the following error:

```
GRASS 6.4.3svn (India_01):~ > i.maxlik group=test_group@test subgroup=test_group sigfile=test_sigfiles1 class=test_results1
ERROR: Unable to read signature file <test_sigfiles1>
```

I'm not sure what other information I should provide. Can anyone suggest the possible reasons for this error? I've tried using i.cluster to generate an unsupervised signature file, and i.maxlik reads this perfectly well.

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure the output sigfile from `i.class` is named `test_sigfiles1`? Just checking..

Comment: Yes - checked and double checked. If the file name is entered wrongly the error is 'Unable to open signature file <wrong filename>, so there seems to be something wrong with the file itself.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? What is the console response/output after the completion of `i.class`? Can you provide the signature file itself?

Comment: Note: This is a pretty old question from GRASS GIS 6!

Answer (score 1):

I've had this error from `i.cluster`, so not exactly the same as you, but I've fixed it by changing the options of my clusterring.  In my case, I've set the minimum number of pixels per class (`min_size`) to be too high in comparaison to the number of class/pixels in my limited calculation region.  So I think people experiencing this error should play around there different clustering options.